# Getting error 422 when updating a Statuspage component via the Postman API - how do I fix this?

Tags: statuspage-api

Ive been trying to figure out how to update a component in status page via Postman API.

Ive gone through the statuspage API documentation below

https://developer.statuspage.io/

I've initiated the PATCH API request to update the component by giving API key, page_id and component_id of the respective status page.

given the component group value to group_id , description and name of a statuspage.io
JSON:

{
"component": {
"description": "string",
"status": "operational",
"name": "string",
"only_show_if_degraded": true,
"group_id": "string",
"showcase": true,
"start_date": "2023-05-23"
}
}

After sending the request, it throws Error:422 (Unprocessable entity) stating that

{
"error": [
"You have downtime data recorded prior to the start date you selected. Delete that data (incident or maintenance) in order to select this date."
]
}

Ive checked  there is no down time data in my status page to delete(from incidents or maintenance).

Please let me know how to proceed to resolve this issue. what could be the possible areas to look into?

Thank you in advance
:)